# Debian Linux script files and data files location

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Debian Linux system setup. I have written various shell script files to do various tasks, some python scripts. These scripts output data files for storage, and other scripts act on the data files to produce more data files.

At the moment, all of these files are held in one folder under roots home directory.

Question is, where should they really go ?

Should script files go into /usr/bin ???

Where do data files go, home directory ???

What are the general rules.

Comment: It's your system, so your rules. But if the scripts are only for a single user, then don't put them into the system bin directories - that'd make them available to everyone. ditto for data files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to be able to give a helpful answer, but all I can say is "probably not" and "it depends".

"/usr/bin" on Debian should usually be the domain of the package system. Don't put stuff there by hand, unless you really have to.

Your stuff should probably not live in "/root" (which I figure is what you mean by "roots home directory"), but instead of the home of some other user account. Maybe /home/admin, assuming your user account is named admin. But manly because you should not ever log in as root, except for system recovery.

You need to be more specific about what you are doing and why. If you are just messing around in a sandbox system to learn unix scripting, then the answer is probably "it does not matter".

Answer (score 1):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html

Answer (score 1):

@askovpen is close, but Debian has its own [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY).  On Debian, local packages go in the `/usr/local` subdirectories, which are already in the path.  The document has info on where the various data files go.